# Clustering Categorical Data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, categorical-data, k-means, k-medoids

I want to cluster a data set where all variables are categorical.

Which would be more effective for doing so, k - means or k - medoids?

The data set is linked below.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/congressional+voting+records

Answer (score 1):

As K-medoids  minimizes a sum of pairwise dissimilarities instead K-means minimizes sum of squared Euclidean distances.

If the data is categorical the medoids are more perfect as it is more robust towards outlier and noise.

So use K-medoids

Answer (score 1):

K-means needs to compute *means*.

Hence it cannot be used on categoricial data.

You can do hacks such as one-hot encoding but these have their own issues. That is why method such as k-modes exist...